# This code: "performClick()", doesn't work completely?

Tags: android

```
    CheckBox1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (CheckBox1.isChecked()) {
                doThis();
            } else {
                doThis();
            }
        }
    });


 private void doThis() {
       String sar="1";   

       try {
        if (sar.equals("")) {
            l_view.performItemClick(l_view, Integer.parseInt(Integer.parseInt(sar)), l_view.getItemIdAtPosition(Integer.parseInt(sar)));
        }
        if (sar.equals("1")) {
            l_view.performItemClick(l_view, Integer.parseInt(Integer.parseInt(sar)), l_view.getItemIdAtPosition(Integer.parseInt(sar)));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

This code works very well if I click the checkbox manually.

But if I use `CheckBox1.performClick();` checkbox is checked but `doThis()` not working.

How can I do this? Thanks for helping.

Comment: use `CheckBox1.setOnCheckChangedListener` instead of `setOnClickListener()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution this. Thanks for helping.

```
private void delay() {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           doThis();
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your onClickListener to this

```
    CheckBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    doThis();
                } else {
                    doThis();
                }
            }
        });
```

[image: See this Image]

Comment: performClick() call the listener check your own self.

Comment: Thanks Sabish, but same result. If I click manualy checkbox doThis(); is working. But performClick() in onCreate doesn't work again.